# select multiple columns which are null for a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 1 id column and 3 int columns.
Data is inserted in this way

```
insert into table (col1, col2) values (1,1) 

insert into table (col2, col3) values (1,1)

insert into table (col1, col3) values (1,1)

insert into table (col1) values (1)
```

then,
row 1, col 3 is null
row 2, col 1 is null,
row 3, col 2 is null.
row 4, col 2 and col 3 are null.

I want to replace the null values with 0. How can I do that?

Note: I won't know which columns are null, so i can't use     `ISNULL(colname, 0)`

Comment: Use `ISNULL` on each column. What's the problem?

Comment: so I do a for loop through all the columns?

Comment: Look at at the answers given by DeanOC or Gordon below. There's no for loop as such, you just do `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` for each column to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update the table so the `NULL`s become `0`, use `coalesce()`:

```
update table t
    set col1 = coalesce(col1, 0),
        col2 = coalesce(col2, 0),
        col3 = coalesce(col3, 0)
    where col1 is null or col2 is null or col3 is null;
```

`coalesce()` is the ANSI-standard function for replacing a `NULL` value with something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert `0` to columns by default, you can alter the table and set `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` to needed column

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD DEFAULT(0) FOR Col1
```

*No **UPDATE** statement required*

Anyhow you need to update existing records using UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update table set co1 = ISNULL(col1,0), col2 = ISNULL(col2, 0), col3 = ISNULL(col3, 0)
```

if the value in col1, 2 or 3 is not null then it will be replaced with the same value, otherwise if null then it will be replaced with 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to replace a possibly null column with something else, use [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

```
 SELECT ISNULL(myColumn, 0 ) FROM myTable
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3),0) FROM Table
```

Comment: so I do a for loop through all the columns?

Comment: @Splunk, i believe your last statement could be written without the ISNULL ie, SELECT COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3, 0) FROM Table

Answer (score 0):

I'll accept Gordon's, but in the end I did this, because my number of columns can change and I wanted it to be specific to certain rows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [setNullToZero]
    @rowSID VARCHAR(60) = 'A'
AS
BEGIN
declare @column_name as varchar(100)
declare col cursor for
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'dlgroups' 
ORDER BY ordinal_position;


open col;
fetch next from col into @column_name;
while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
begin
if (@column_name != 'id')
    exec('Update dlgroups set '+ @column_name +'=ISNULL('+@column_name+',0) WHERE sid='''+@rowSID+'''')

fetch next from col into @column_name
end
close col
deallocate col
END
GO
```